# Does the GUID or UUID of a partition change on resizing the partitions?

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount, resizing

Q1) Does the GUID or UUID of a partition change on resizing the partitions?

I have a partition with lot of free space(windows partition) and another with little free space (ext4 --> / (root partition). They both are adjacent (first windows, then Linux partition) to each other. So I am thinking of shrinking windows partiton and then expanding the other Linux partion.

I am using Ubuntu and windows 10 Dual boot?

After resizing, will the `/` partition still have the same UUID/GUID. If it does then I don't think there will be any issue with mounting during bootup.

Q2) Even if the UUID/GUID's change, will there be any issue with Linux mounting the `/` partiton after resizing?

Answer (score 4):

Sane partitioning tools shouldn't change the UUID when resizing. I'm not aware of any that would. `parted`, *GParted*, *Disk Management* and `diskpart` will leave UUID unchanged.

As @KamilMaciorowski noted in the comments, `fdisk` and `gdisk` don't provide single-step partition resizing. Instead, you're supposed to delete a partition and create a new one with adjusted size. This does not destroy the data (partition layout is stored separately), but will generate a new UUID for the new partition. (You should also shrink the filesystem first before shrinking its partition.)

Whether changing UUID would cause boot problems depends on your configuration. Partitions can be identified by device order (unreliable), UUIDs, GPT labels or filesystem labels. UUIDs are the default identifier for all distros I know (except for Arch maybe, which is DIY) so if you're using defaults, changing partition UUID will prevent OS from booting.

As always, make backups before editing partitions. It's handy if things go south. I'd recommend Clonezilla.

Comment: +1, Clonezilla is superb. The only issue is, I have about 1TB data and its gonna take lot of time. But i get your point.

Comment: @samshers It would hurt to lose 1 TB of precious data :)

Comment: I think at least `fdisk` does not provide a way to literally resize a partition. The usual way to do it is to delete the old entry in the partition table and to create a new entry *anew*. These are *separate* operations and the tool doesn't save UUID(s). "Sane partitioning tools shouldn't change the UUID", true, but here the entry is formally *destroyed*, not changed. The tool treats the new partition as a separate entity. It's the user's job to re-create the Type-UUID and the UUID, if this is what they want. More sophisticated tools that have an explicit concept of resizing will preserve IDs.

Comment: @Kamil You're right, apparently I haven't used `fdisk` in a while. Answer updated.